# C# Windows Forms Resolution on Microsoft Surface

Tags: c#, winforms, surface-pro

Recently I bought a Microsoft Surface Pro 4 and I'm using it as my main computer for development.

I was trying to create a project in C# using Windows Forms and I faced a problem.
The resolution of the form that I am designing does not matches the resolution of the form that is displayed when I'm debugging the program.

In my old laptop this did not happen, I think it is because of the resolution of my surface screen, but I need to fix this somehow.

In the print-screen below you can see the problem: [Print-Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGT0I.png)

UPDATE: Check how the components align when I debug the program:
[image]

Comment: have you changed some form properties like autoscalemode etc..?

Comment: This may be help: https://code4ward.net/2016/11/29/visual-studio-winforms-designer-on-highdpi/

Comment: Check the zoom setting in the windows 10 display settings. My experience is the surface tablets default to 150% which blows up your windows forms.

Comment: But If I set the zoom to 100% I'm not able to see nothing... The default zoom that comes with surface is 200%